# New artists per year/month for music streaming services

Tags: data-request, music

I'm trying to get some stats for the number of new artists on music streaming service per year or month, weather that's Spotify, YouTube, Beat music, etc. it doesn't matter.

I've tried searching for this information somewhere but I can only find that Spotify has 20,000 new songs per day. I could maybe make the assumption that every 15 songs is a new artist but that probably isn't very accurate.